# Is a polynomial group law on $\mathbb{R}^n$ automatically nilpotent?

Tags: lie-groups, polynomials, reference-request

I was told that a polynomial group law on (all of) $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives automatically a nilpotent (Lie, of course) group.

Is it true? Where can I find a proof?

A counterexample for open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is furnished by the halfplane with the $ax+b$ law.

Comment: Torsten, make it an answer (not just a comment).

Comment: Moved a comment to an answer as per instructions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is true and is in "Michel Lazard: Sur la nilpotence de certains groupes algébriques, Comptes Rendus, vol 241, 1955, 1687--1689"

Comment: This short paper is apparently not available online, but a version of
Lazard's theorem is also written down in the 1970 book by Demazure-Gabriel, *Groupes algebriques, I*:  see IV, section 4, 4.1.  